i have a blue dashed line
I have a blue dashed line in following path constraints and not moving car only a revolve line what was the solution ?? please guide  me


Hello, could you please share your file?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19YyOX01coiAe2aV1LZkU_6gfl7EO6b0s/view?usp=sharing

You are doing it wrong, the mesh doesn't need to be aligned with the curve to make the constraint work.
First thing the origin needs to be at the center of your mesh, right click > Set Origin > Geometry to Origin, rotate the mesh so that it's aligned with the X axis:

Then set the constraint this way, Forward Axis > X, Up Axis > Z, activate Follow Curve:


Thank you Very very much brother you have a social media account I would be very happy to follow my teacher I m from India. and once again I will be very thankful to you love you brother

You're welcome  ;)  i have a youtube channel but it's in french

Blender Moonboots in English AND in French I subscribe the both channels thanks again brother

Yes but I've been too lazy to develop the english one   ;)
